# Moshi Retrofit Request

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I'm doing a POST request and I'm using
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)

And the request body is as follow:

```
{
    "request": "some data",
    "data": {}
}
```

When creating my data class, how could I declare the empty object "data" = {}

My data class is as follow:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Request(val request: String, val data: ?)
```

But, how could I create the empty body?

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be nullable type of necessary class with 'null' default value, so like:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Request(val request: String, val data: MyData? = null)
```

I think it will works.